# Docker install failed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am trying to install docker on windows 10. I therefore downloaded the installer as per the official documentation, but when I execute it I get the following error:

Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"message":"1 error occurred:\n\t* starting WSL integration service: synchronising agents: starting added distros: 1 error occurred:\n\t* waiting for WSL integration for Ubuntu: timed out while polling for WSL distro integration to become ready in "Ubuntu"\n\n\n\n"}

at Docker.Core.GoBackend.GoBackendClient.d__19.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\GoBackend\GoBackendClient.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.d__11.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.d__15.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Engines.Engines.d__23.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 109

I tried installing multiple times, with and without admin privileges.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows OS, your need to install Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL.

Here is a link to install it :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I did install WSL, to no avail...